# React native upload image as binary using rn-fetch-blob

Tags: javascript, react-native, rn-fetch-blob

I am trying to upload an image as binary. I used rn-fetch-blob library for this one. Because normal fetch gives network errors.

```
const path = file.path.replace('file://', '');
const uploadPath = RNFetchBlob.wrap(path);

RNFetchBlob.fetch(
    'PUT',
      SERVER_URL,
      uploadPath,
  )
    .then(res => {
      console.log('image uploaded res ---> ',res);
    })
    .catch(err => {
      console.log(err);
    });
```

it uploads an empty stream and the server stores a zero-byte size file. Any solution for this issue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> it uploads an empty stream and the server stores a zero-byte size file. Any solution for this issue?

This is because it is not able to find the image file at the `path specified`. Can you please try something like this and let me know ?

```
  const filePath = Platform.OS === 'ios'
 ? res.path().replace('file:///', '').replace('file://', '')
 : res.path().replace('file://', '').replace('file:/', '');

  RNFetchBlob.fetch('PUT', 'your-server-url', {
   // this is required, otherwise it won't be processed as a multipart/form-data request
    'Content-Type' : 'multipart/form-data',
  }, [
    // append field data from file path
    {
      name : 'test',
      filename : 'test.png',
      // Change BASE64 encoded data to a file path with prefix `RNFetchBlob-file://`.
      // Or simply wrap the file path with RNFetchBlob.wrap().
      data: RNFetchBlob.wrap(filePath)
    }
  ]).then((resp) => {
    // ...
  }).catch((err) => {
    // ...
  })
```

Hope it helps

Comment: Got an error like this <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>\n<Error><Cod…sGZt5pHOdVeTeC2DCa3PXqtedzQ7clA=</HostId></Error>

Comment: what is the exact error message please? Can you please check if this error occurs in server side? If yes, you will need to resolve that first.

Comment: "The request signature we calculated does not match the signature you provided. Check your key and signing method" This was the error

Comment: are you uploading the file to `Amazon S3` by any chance or is it on some other server?

Comment: Finally, it's working. Thanks. Yep It's S3